# What is cube attack and trivium cypher?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, block-cipher, mac, authenticated-encryption

Actually i am studying cube attack so there is some confusion regarding that in my mind this is

1- it is used for MAC KEY RECOVERY

2- It is a test that user performs to check the frogery or MAC or encryption

3- It is used to break encryption

4- cube attack have paper test like xor etc so they are performed for validty and consistency check

5- trivium cypher is encryption methodology of crypto so when they performed on that they decrypt the information to some extent

6- cypher text is encrypted string having data can cube attack is used to decrypt that

so regarding that above mentioned point can any body tell me where i am right and wrong and add some knowledge and tell me they are used some things correct about trivium cypher and cube attacks

Answer (score 2):

*Cube attack* is the name given by Itai Dinur and Adi Shamir to a general attack on cryptographic schemes considered as multivariate polynomial equations, in their paper [*Cube Attacks on Tweakable Black Box Polynomials*](http://eprint.iacr.org/2008/385.pdf) (in [proceedings of EuroCrypt 2009](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-01001-9_16)). The origin and applicability of the attack has been [challenged by Daniel Bernstein](http://cr.yp.to/cubeattacks.html).

The attack aims at key recovery from plaintext/ciphertext pairs, with chosen plaintext. It is applicable to encryption and MACs using vulnerable block or stream ciphers.

For example, *if* one used a *modified* [Trivium](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/triviumpf.html) with only 767 initialization rounds instead of the prescribed 1152, the key could be recovered under a chosen-plaintext attack; that would compromise confidentiality and integrity of messages protected by that same key.

Thus, 1/3/5 in the question apply to some degree, for that modified Trivium.

It seems that 2/4/6 in the question do not apply (I'm reading 6 as trying to break encryption under known plaintext).

---

Addition following [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/40518/555#comment92470_40520): In good practice, neither of 1/2/3/4/5/6 apply. A standard cipher design criteria has been (for over 20 years) to avoid the conditions that allow [higher-order differential cryptanalysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_differential_cryptanalysis) to work; modern ciphers that survived analysis by competent cryptographers are thus practically immune to the cube attack (including AES in all key sizes and standard modes). As an aside, the cube attack requires *chosen* plaintext, thus typically does not apply if all that gets encrypted using a key is chosen by legitimate holders of that key, which seems to be the hypothesis made [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/40518/555#comment92469_40520).

Comment: so suppose i encrypt my file using encryption with a key can cube attack possibly break that key and get the information out of it so, this comes in eye view of hacking or broot force category i am right according to 3,5,6

Comment: i have practically implemented StringCypher cryptography that encrypts the plain text with a file with password and key size 256 but i used that same key and initVectorBytes to decrypt files .. so you mean using cube attack i can decrypt that with out using my password and key